# recurse xml, howto select elements based on a condition of its children

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have an xml file with a structure as indicated below.

Question: How do I select/query those elements with children where the sum(amount) from its children is unequal to its own amount?

There is no fixed amount of children and there are even elements with no children, these later elements should not appear in the selection.

File structure arising from a json bubbletree file:

```
    '<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
     <xs:element name="JSON">
     <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
       <xs:element ref="label"/>
       <xs:element ref="amount"/>
       <xs:element ref="color"/>
       <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="children"/>
      </xs:sequence>
     </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="label" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="amount" type="xs:integer"/>
    <xs:element name="color" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="children">
     <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
       <xs:element ref="amount"/>
       <xs:element ref="children"/>
       <xs:element ref="color"/>
       <xs:element ref="label"/>
      </xs:choice>
     </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
   </xs:schema>'
```

arising from a bubblechart json file.

I'm after the elements where a label starts with a 'x' (put in manually to clarify, is not there in the real files) in the following xml file:

```
   '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <JSON>
   <label>total</label>
   <amount>30</amount>
    <children>
        <label>x 1</label>
        <amount>10</amount>
            <children>
                <label>1.1</label>
                <amount>5</amount>
            </children>
            <children>
                <label>1.2</label>
                <amount>6</amount>
            </children>
    </children>
    <children>
        <label>2</label>
        <amount>10</amount>
            <children>
                <label>2.1</label>
                <amount>5</amount>
            </children>
            <children>
                <label>x 2.2</label>
                <amount>5</amount>
                    <children>
                        <label>2.2.1</label>
                        <amount>3</amount>
                    </children>
                    <children>
                        <label>2.2.2</label>
                        <amount>1</amount>
                    </children>
                    <children>
                        <label>2.2.3</label>
                        <amount>3</amount>
                    </children>
            </children>
    </children>
    <children>
        <label>x 3</label>
        <amount>10</amount>
            <children>
                <label>3.1</label>
                <amount>5</amount>
            </children>
            <children>
                <label>3.2</label>
                <amount>6</amount>
            </children>
    </children>
   </JSON>'
```

Comment: Do you want to process the descendants of an element or only its children?

Comment: I want to loop trough the whole file and I want every node where the amount value is not equal to the sum of the amounts in its children element. Each children element is then the basis for a new loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this expression to select all children elements, with children themselves, where the amount is not equal to the sum of children amount

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="//children[children][amount != sum(children/amount)]" />
```

For example, with this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//children[children][amount != sum(children/amount)]" />
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="children">
      <children><xsl:value-of select="label" /></children>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The following children are selected

```
<children>x 1</children>
<children>x 2.2</children>
<children>x 3</children>
```